# Locate resource using classloader or File?

Tags: java, file, classloader

I'm reading someone elses code; they have a line like so:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("../../../../../../file.txt");
```

Why would you do this instead of using `File`? Isn't the point of using the classloader to locate resources on the said classloaders classpath?

Comment: possible duplicate of [getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)

Answer (score 1):

`getResourceAsStream()` allows you get access to files inside the JAR-container.

Comment: hm, and what if the relative path defined above is different within the jar?